# Translating batch script to AHK for further development

Tags: android, batch-file, autohotkey

This is part of the batch script to extract MTK android boot.img that i got stuck, shared by a DEV.

An AHK newbie myself, as the title says and got stuck with *loop*, %boot_size% & *cpio* not extracting to *rmdisk* folder...

```
set /A N=0
:loop
FOR /F %%G IN (bin\off2.txt) DO (
    if !N!==1 (
        set /A ofs1=%%G
        set /A N+=1
    )
    if !N!==3 (
        set /A ofs2=%%G
        set /A N+=1
    )
    if !N!==5 (
        set /A ofs3=%%G+4
        set /A N+=1
    )   
    if `%%G` EQU `offset` (
            set /A N+=1
    )
)
FOR %%i IN (%1) DO ( set /A boot_size=%%~Zi )

md %~N1

bin\sfk166.exe partcopy %1 -fromto 0x0 %ofs1% %~N1\kernel_header -yes

bin\sfk166.exe partcopy %1 -fromto %ofs1% %ofs2% %~N1\kernel -yes

bin\sfk166.exe partcopy %1 -fromto %ofs2% %ofs3% %~N1\ram_header -yes

bin\sfk166.exe partcopy %1 -fromto %ofs3% %boot_size% %~N1\ram_disk.gz -yes

bin\7z.exe -tgzip x -y %~N1\ram_disk.gz -o%~N1 >nul

md %~N1\rmdisk
cd %~N1
cd rmdisk
%~dp0bin\cpio.exe -i <../ram_disk
```

Any help is greatly appreciated... ;-)

TIA

---

@*MCL*
Thanks for your reply. First part of the script is like a direct translation so it just worked... :-P

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

RunWait, %comspec% /c %A_ScriptDir%\bin\sfk166.exe hexfind %A_ScriptDir%\recovery.img -pat -bin /88168858/ -case>%A_ScriptDir%\bin\offset.txt, , min
RunWait, %comspec% /c %A_ScriptDir%\bin\sfk166.exe hexfind %A_ScriptDir%\recovery.img -pat -bin /FFFFFFFF1F8B08/ -case>>%A_ScriptDir%\bin\offset.txt , , min
RunWait, %comspec% /c %A_ScriptDir%\bin\sfk166.exe find %A_ScriptDir%\bin\offset.txt -pat offset>%A_ScriptDir%\bin\off2.txt, , min
RunWait, %comspec% /c %A_ScriptDir%\bin\sfk166.exe replace %A_ScriptDir%\bin\off2.txt -binary /20/0A/ -yes, , min
FileRemoveDir, %A_ScriptDir%/recovery ;to make sure old failed extracted folder is deleted
FileCreateDir, %A_ScriptDir%/recovery
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i've finally translated it & it is working great, guess its true that they say ***AHK*** can execute/ substitute any batch command . . .

The key solution to this is to understand what the batch script trying to do & substitute it with ***AHK*** command. Execute it one command per line & see what it does . . .

This is what i did, add **echo %ofs1% %ofs2% %ofs3% %boot_size%** to the batch script & the below command . . .

```
yourbatchfile.bat>log.txt
```

Analyse the *log.txt* content & it will give you some idea what to do next . . . Good Luck ;-)